# Sound libraries for FL studio

Tags: sound-design, sound, sound-libraries, fl-studio

I start using **FL studio** quite recently. **I would like to expand the set of sounds preinstalled.**

Where can i buy / free download some good **sound libraries**?

Which are the best sounds libraries available?

Which ones do you suggest?

Sorry if is a general question, but i have nowhere else to go and honestly this is the community that most i trust.

Thank you very much!

**EDIT**: I would like actually to specify that i am not interested in ambient sounds (cars, people, nature..) but only in music sounds (for example drums, piano and more synthetic sounds).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basicaly, You can go three ways from here. **Samples, soundfonts and plugins.**

- **Samples** are prerecorded sound files (*.wav most commonly) You can use in your productions. 90% of drums in electronic music is sampled
  for example. But not only drums. There are whole genres that are very
  sample influenced, such as hip-hop in general, early drum and bass,
  jungle or various house styles. You can find sample banks consisting
  of instruments recorded note-by-note, you can find drum loops and
  sound effects, even banks of premade riffs. There's all manner of
  stuff out there. There are some prime, top of the game libraries and
  publishers souch as **Loopmasters** or **samplephonics** which very
  seldom will be a miss, but the market is ever-expanding and new stuff
  pops up every day. Search "Sample Library" in google, and you'll come
  up with something soon enough. **bedroomproducersblog.com** is great
  place to visit every few days in search of free stuff, samples too.
- **Soundfonts** on the other hand are halfway between samples and synths. Not yet independent plugins, but not samples either. It's
  more like soundbank in one file, with sounds already mapped across
  the keyboard. Again, as with samples, you can get them in all flavors
  drums, instruments, effects, synthetic and accoustic. Almost all of the soundfont players (including the one inside FL) have basic
  modulation functionality such as filters, envelopes and so on, so
  it's relatively easy to tweak the sound.

  Lastly, there are **VST plugins** (in that case VSTi, where i is for
  an instrument) which are regular instruments. Again, all manner of
  stuff - synths, samplers, drum machines. The main difference between
  VSTi and other stuff I mentioned is that it's live, not recorded. The
  sound is actually being made by the plugin itself. You can shape it
  however you want, you can tweak it, you can create from scratch, just
  like with a hardware equivalent. There are thousands of free and
  commercial synths out there, plenty to chose from.  Aforementioned
  **bedroomproducersblog** does great job informing people about newest free synths and effects being released, they got lists of best
  freeware plugins divided by categories and such, so I strongly
  encourage you to give them a go. **kvraudio.com** is another very
  usefull place - they run biggest database of probablly all the
  plugins ever released, free and commercial. They got great, newbie
  friendly forums too. I learned a lot from them. **Gearslutz.com** is
  another great web forums for the indepth knowledge.

**JUST DIG IN AND YOU'LL GONNA BE FINE :)**

Comment: Thank you for the reply and to make clear the difference! Precious info for a beginner! :)

Comment: I forgot to add - FLStudio devs too offer extra soundbanks and plugins on their website. Paid stuff, but high quality and easy accessability, you can get them even from within the FLS itself.

Comment: Ah thanks. I found the link: https://support.image-line.com/jshop/shop.php

They seem expensive indeed, but probably as you said they are worth it.